# is_admin() and DOING_AJAX in Wordpress Plugins

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

Im developing a Wordpress-plugin, where the main file of the plugins includes a PHP-file depending on (supposed to at least) if you are back-end or front-end.

As the is_admin() returns true on AJAX requests, I have used the DOING_AJAX constant to check whetever AJAX is done or not:

```
if ( is_admin() && ( ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) || ! DOING_AJAX ) ) {
    require_once('admin/functions_admin.php'); 
 }
 else { 
    require_once('public/functions_public.php'); 
 }
```

The correct file is loaded in wp-admin. The correct file is loaded front-end. Ajax-requests works front-end - **but not back end**. The "if" is not executed when doing Ajax back-end with this code.

When adding the following "else if" code it works back-end, but then not frond-end of course:

```
else if ( is_admin() ) {
   require_once('admin/functions_admin.php'); 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorted this out by gathering all AJAX-functions (both front- and back-end) in a third file:

```
// Is admin, but not doing ajaax
if ( is_admin() && ( ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) || ! DOING_AJAX ) ) {
    require_once('admin/functions_admin.php'); 
}
// Is doing AJAX 
else if ( is_admin() && ( defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) || DOING_AJAX ) ) {
    require_once('functions_ajax.php'); 
}
// Front-end functions
else { 
require_once('public/functions_public.php'); 
}
```

Comment: That's a terrible technique and it looks like you are avoiding the WordPress guidelines (and aides) for using AJAX in plugins and the admin. Please read... https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Comment: Is it such terrible technique? WordPress is not even able to keep its is_admin() true when using the funky block editor, thus, what is so wrong with above proper check for is_admin? It is the only thing that *really* checks if it is admin or not. Everything else "suggested by wordpress" does either not exist or is not correct, see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_admin/#comment-4939, and https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_admin/#comment-513

Comment: I love WordPress but agree with Beda's comment. If there is no is_not_admin_really_I_swear_no_ajax_no_nothing function then you have to check somehow yourself. I don't know if I would use the technique to decide whether I include a file or not, but the check logic  itself is not incorrect

Comment: It's not that terrible, he just wants to load some files on different scenarios and he does. But the if's could be simplified checking the ajax on the first branch or just using ``is_admin()`` on the second branch because the second part of the ``&&`` will always be true if the 1st one is true

Comment: The logic is fine - apart from `||` should be `&&` in `elseif` - is not terrible technique (whatever you mean by technique), and I've resorted to similar myself.  My code doesn't know what plugin or theme might be doing AJAX, or whether it might be for the front end or the admin panel - and has no way of knowing.  @BA_Webimax, I can't see anything helpful in that link.  The terrible technique is the way WordPress was 'designed' (or in fact not), which we are now all stuck with.

Answer (score 7):

There is a note about this fact on the Ajax in plugin codex page.

As the hook use `wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` you must avoid using is_admin(), that will Always returns true.

An example, you want to include a file only on front end, you check with `!is_admin()`, in the file you have the `wp_ajax_{$action}` , but admin-ajax.php will Always return true, and the response will be 0.

What the codex says;

> Both front-end and back-end Ajax requests use admin-ajax.php so is_admin() will always return true in your action handling code.
>
> When selectively loading your Ajax script handlers for the front-end and back-end, and using the is_admin() function, your wp_ajax_(action) and wp_ajax_nopriv_(action) hooks MUST be inside the is_admin() === true part.

So, if your question is : how can i make my script works ?

Remove `is_admin()` and replace it with another conditional.

Source [Ajax in plugin](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins)

Hope it helps

Comment: My plugin was not initializing properly when a 3rd party plugin was using `admin-ajax.php` on the front end, because I had separate initialization for 'admin' and front end.  I hope this was just an optimization (can't remember), and a quick fix will be to check `DOING_AJAX` and if set initialize both.  (Can't help thinking that AJAX via WordPress's built-in mechanism will be very slow.)

Comment: PS. Guess there is no way to tell if an AJAX request via `admin-ajax.php` has actually come from the front end of a 3rd party theme or plugin, or via the admin panels, so you will have to cater for both cases wherever applicable in your own theme or plugin.  And not reveal sensitive data when it's from the front end, which you have no way of knowing.  So need to check the current logged-on user's permissions.

Answer (score 0):

There is a specific function to perform this task: [wp_doing_ajax()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_doing_ajax)

Comment: providing an example would be nicer

Comment: It's equivalent to the condition in the OP.  The OP was not asking for help tidying up their code.