# Wordpress pre_get_posts action : check if current query is for admin dashboard or not

Tags: wordpress

I'm going to filter post types and show only published posts on frontend when searching.
So I used this code to do this.

```
function custom_search_preprocess($wp_query) {
    if ($wp_query->is_search() && get_search_query() && $wp_query->is_main_query()) {
    $wp_query->set('post_type', array(
       'page','post', 'movie',
    ));
    $wp_query->set('post_status', 'publish');
}
```

It's working well.
But I noticed it's affecting on admin dashboard.
When on admin dashboard, it's only showing published posts when searching.
I know there is a WP function to check this. `is_admin()`
So I use that function and below is the updated code.

```
function custom_search_preprocess($wp_query) {
    if(is_admin()) return;
    if ($wp_query->is_search() && get_search_query() && $wp_query->is_main_query()) {
    $wp_query->set('post_type', array(
       'page','post', 'movie',
    ));
    $wp_query->set('post_status', 'publish');
}
```

But this function returns true when AJAX calling on frontend.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Are you by chance doing this because private posts are showing up in the search results? Private posts will only show up for Editors and Administrators as per [documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Content_Visibility#Private_Content), so you wouldn't have to worry about that from a regular user standpoint.

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/30638/determining-whether-its-a-ajax-call-from-front-end-or-from-back-end OR https://snippets.khromov.se/determine-if-wordpress-ajax-request-is-a-backend-of-frontend-request/

Comment: @mcon It's not private or public. It's draft or publish.

Comment: how did you register your ajax request?

Comment: @Noman add_action('wp_ajax_load_more', 'load_more_func');

Comment: Your `is_admin` should be placed somewhere else or use another conditional, I think this may be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40891998/is-admin-and-doing-ajax-in-wordpress-plugins